# RxJava - testing subscribeOn()

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming

I want to use RxJava in my project and I wrote simple asynchronous method and now I try to test it. I cannot test it with Executor because I get result: `java.lang.AssertionError: Not completed! (0 completions)`

**Service method:**

```
    @Override
    public Observable<User> addOrderAsynchronously(String username, Order order) {
        if (username != null && order != null) {
            return Observable
                    .fromCallable(() -> userRepository.findByUsername(username))
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(user -> {
                        synchronized (this) {
                             user.getOrders().add(order);
                             order.setUser(user);
                        }
                         return user;
                    })
                    .map(userRepository::save);
    }
    return Observable.empty();
}
```

**Working test without Executor:**

```
@Test
public void shouldSaveUserSynchronouslyTest() throws Exception {
    // given
    TestSubscriber<User> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    final Order order = new Order();
    final User user = new User();

    when(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()))
            .thenReturn(user);

    when(userRepository.save(any(User.class)))
            .thenReturn(user);

    // when
    userService.addOrderAsynchronously(user.getUsername(), order)
            .subscribe(subscriber);

    // then
    subscriber.assertCompleted();
    subscriber.assertNoErrors();
    assertThat(subscriber.getOnNextEvents()).isEqualTo(Collections.singletonList(user));
}
```

**And now I want to test with executor:**

```
@Test
    public void shouldSaveUserSynchronouslyTest() throws Exception {
        // given
        TestSubscriber<User> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
        final Order order = new Order();
        final User user = new User();

        when(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()))
                .thenReturn(user);

        when(userRepository.save(any(User.class)))
                .thenReturn(user);

        // when
        userService.addOrderAsynchronously(user.getUsername(), order)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor))
                .subscribe(subscriber);

        // then
        subscriber.assertCompleted();
        subscriber.assertNoErrors();
        assertThat(subscriber.getOnNextEvents()).isEqualTo(Collections.singletonList(user));
    }
```

And this test doesn't work because I get result `java.lang.AssertionError: Not completed! (0 completions)`.

**executor is comes from @Bean method:**

```
@Bean
public Executor executor() {
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(8);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(8);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

How can I write unit test with executor?

Comment: See [awaitTerminalEvent()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html#awaitTerminalEvent--).

Comment: Furthermore to @akarnokd answer: Please do not use synchronized in operators or modify elements in pipeline. Everything I said is explained in this book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920042228.do